# Can't download the GCP could function source

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created an inline cloud function on GCP. I wanted to download the source and develop offline and upload later time. So I clicked the download zip button as below.
[image: download-zip-button]

Anyway I am getting failed forbidden error. I have logged into my google account while downloading the zip.

[image: failed-forbidden-error]

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I too would like to know why the down vote!

Answer (score 3):

For me, this happens when I am logged into multiple Google accounts. It looks like the "Download zip" link isn't appending the "authuser=X" flag and so the download is attempted as the wrong user.

To fix this, I copied the link for the "Download zip" button, added the same "authuser=X" value as I had in my Google Cloud Console URL, and then everything worked.

Comment: Great catch! Seems like this problem occurs in a lot of places throughout Google sites